# How to list all scopes?

Tags: systemd, scope

On my journald logs, i see entries like:

```
systemd[865]: app-org.kde.konsole-fbe1036742844b1ea3cd54e064c0a794.scope: Killing process 14893
```

Aparently konsole does start one scope per instance (and there's a bug to add one per tab) but having several `konsole`s open, i get:

```
$ systemctl list-unit-files --all | grep konsole
$ systemctl list-units --all | grep konsole
$ systemctl list-units --type scope
init.scope
session-1.scope
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are managed not by PID1 but by your per-user systemd instance.

Use `systemctl --user` to list the per-user units (and `systemd-cgls` to get an overview of where the user services live in relation to the main service manager).

Comment: sigh. makes `--all` kinda pointless and misleading. assumed --user was a filter not a switch to a hidden namespace. thank you!